# Arrays in scheme / Memoization

Tags: scheme, racket, dynamic-programming, memoization

How can I use arrays in Scheme?

In particular, I'm attempting to implement a recursive fibonacci procedure using memoization. Do arrays even exist in Scheme?

If not, how can I implement memoization?

Comment: For such questions it is often very useful to specify which implementation you're using.  Memoization is common enough in Scheme that most implementations would come with some library.

Comment: I had the implementation as a tag, but it seems sgm edited it out (probably rightly so as I think I was creating the tag by using it). I'm using Pretty Big Scheme (DrScheme).

Comment: Actually, I just chose PBS from DrScheme's Choose Language menu - I have no idea which one I should use. Apprently PLT and r5rs are popular?

Comment: In this case you should have used `plt-scheme` as the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are arrays in Scheme, but they are called [vectors](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.3.6). Be aware that they don't resize like they do in other languages like Perl and Javascript, or the like-named C++ thing; you have to make a bigger one and copy the contents of the obsolete one over.

If you want to know more about memoization and dynamic programming in particular, you can read chapter 12 of the free book [*Concrete Abstractions*](http://gustavus.edu/+max/concrete-abstractions-pdfs/index.html).

Comment: `they don't resize; you have to make a bigger one and copy the contents of the obsolete one over.` Sounds exactly like an array from any other language. Are there any subtle differences I should be aware of (let's say, between scheme vectors and c arrays)? Thanks!

Comment: I guess just that scheme vector elements can contain any object like any other variable or cons cell, and not limited to "array of _____".

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer, so feel free to downvote etc: if you're using PLT and you need memoization then you should look at Dave Herman's [memoize package](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=memoize.plt&owner=dherman).  Also, you could grab the memoize function from the swindle library.

Comment: Is pretty big scheme PLT? I'm a bit confused with regards to what 'PLT Scheme' is.

Comment: Yes, "Pretty big" is the name of a language level in DrScheme, all part of the PLT Scheme language which is what you're using.  (And the project is being renamed these days to Racket, partly to avoid such confusions.)